# How to find errors in an Angular2 project?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I started to learn Angular2 and I have a beginner question. I work with many files and in case of code error I don't know where to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Error debugging is not different in Angular2. Its the same as for any other coding language. The few basic steps to debug errors are:

1. Use try-catch blocks.
2. Check error logs in console. From here you will get an idea about what code and in which file you are having issues.
3. Try running the application in debug mode by adding breakpoints and follow the application flow.
4. Use the best practices while coding.

Comment: OK thanks for good tips, but what should I do when unfortunately I forget to set first letter of word to uppercase? For example "import {component}" instead "Component". Its very troublesome...

Comment: Typescript is a strictly typed language. What you can do is to install auto-import extension in VS Code it will automatically give you suggestion on the component you type. If it doesn't find any matching, it will give error indication.